# can I reveal other people public key

Tags: reveal

can I reveal other people public key? Or only self can reveal self public key?

If I send some xtz to a new address to active it, can I reveal its' public key by myself, rather the new address owner?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't reveal other people's public keys. `sender` of a `reveal` operation should be an owner of the public key he reveals.

Comment: You cannot reveal it because you do not have the private key. Keep in mind that you are paying an additional burn fee to send XTZ to a new (zero-balance) address each time you do that.

Comment: Yes, I know about allocation fee, thanks :) As for the private key, I think the author had in mind the case when he knows the private key, since it was he who created that new account. Who knows... :)